# Why does a ping flood wake up a PC, while a single ping does not?

Tags: ping, network-adapter, icmp, wake-on-lan

I just noticed that when you flood-ping a PC that is in sleep-mode, it will wake it up while a single ping or multple pings per 1 sec does not wake it up.

Wake up on lan/wan is enabled.

What is the reason behind this? IMO, it should not turn on at all.

Once its turned on the flood will obviously continue and will result in a frozen or crashed system which is something that we don't want to happen, right?

Could this be a bug in Windows OS? Or could it be the network card itself? When it receives too much data, will start to respond by wakeing it up first and then doing his job?

A ping packet should not make a pc wakeup?

Comment: It depends on the configuration of the NIC and the BIOS.

Comment: If a ping flood crash the system, then it sounds likely there is a bug in the OS.

Comment: Not really a crash but more like a freeze

Answer (score 1):

Normally [WoL](https://wiki.wireshark.org/WakeOnLAN) is triggered using a ["magic packet"](http://support.amd.com/TechDocs/20213.pdf) (6 bytes of 0xFF immediately followed by the MAC address repeated 16 times, anywhere in an Ethernet frame), this is very unlikely to happen by accident.

However, sometimes the NIC is set up to wake the machine based on other types of traffic which are not all that unlikely to be trigger a wakeup by accident.

[Microsoft lists the following defaults](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/941145) in Windows in addition to the "magic packet":

> By default, Windows 7 and Windows Vista listen for the following
>   packets when you enable WOL:
>
> - A directed packet to the MAC address of
>     the network adapter
> - A NetBIOS name resolution broadcast for the local
>     computer name
> - An Address Resolution Protocol (ARP) packet for the IPv4
>     address of the network adapter
> - An IPv6 Neighbor Discovery packet for
>     the network adapter's solicited-node multicast address

As you reference Windows in the question, you may want to ensure that the computer is set to only wake based on a "magic packet" (see above article).

Comment: I would add some more details about the magic packet. The magic packet can be generated remotely, if the target MAC address is already present in ND/ARP cache on the router. If the MAC is not cached, the router will send a request for it. Since the target is sleeping it cannot respond to this request, and thus never gets the wakeup packet. This cyclic dependency prevents waking up the target remotely. But if the target was turned off within the last few minutes, it may work because the MAC is still in the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Hypothesis: NIC is able to repond to a ping itself without involving the OS (a sleep proxy). But when you flood PING, the NIC decides that its incapable of responding to such an event, and must now wake up the PC.

I've heard of such capabilities, but don't know how far along the spectrum from research to reality it is.

What type/model of NIC do you have? What OS/version? BIOS will be involved too.

Comment: Win 8, Realtek GBE/RTL8168.
Unable to enter my bios, usb ports died a year ago, using defalut settings
but i was able to find these on the manfactur site:
- 16Mb AMI BIOS
- AMI Legal BIOS
- Supports "Plug and Play"
- ACPI 1.1 Compliance Wake Up Events
- Supports jumperfree
- SMBIOS 2.3.1 Support
- CPU, VCCM, SB, VTT Voltage Multi-adjustment
- Supports I. O. T. (Intelligent Overclocking Technology)
- Supports Smart BIOS